# Existing PHP/JS Code showing error in import statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, netbeans-8, c3

I received an existing site code in PHP and JS, which I have imported to Netbeans. But the C3js and D3js and jQuery bower components are showing errors for import statements.

Any idea on how to figure it out ?

Comment: What errors are you experiencing and in what environment (browser, IDE, etc)?  Please be specific and include any library versions, tracebacks and other information about your environment, as well as what you've attempted so far.

Comment: what error are you getting?? are you directly importing the project to netbeanns? Or creating a new project?? What import process are you following?

Comment: Hi All, I was setting development environment, and version of IDE is NetBeans 8.0.2 . Browser used is Chrome. Error I received in the js files, was "Expected  operand , and found import" . Later I figured out that the Javascript version used in the existing project is EcmaScript 6, and NetBeans is not supporting that. I switched my IDE to Eclipse and the errors just faded away. :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your netbeans is not able to find the required libraries for that import statement. You need to download those libraries if they are missing.

Comment: As it was an existing project code with all the required libraries in it, I figured out that JS version used is Ecmascript 6 which is not supported by NetBeans.Thanks.